In WOPI Protocal getting error MalformedInputException: Input length = 1 on editing file
This is the error getting on editing the docx file using WOPI
[DEBUG][12 Oct 2024 17:38:34,010] () [o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver] Found key 'FWS_SAVED_FILE_DETAILS_get' in PropertySource 'class path resource [mysql.properties]' with value of type String[DEBUG][12 Oct 2024 17:38:34,011] () [o.s.o.j.JpaTransactionManager] Initiating transaction commit[DEBUG][12 Oct 2024 17:38:34,012] () [o.s.o.j.JpaTransactionManager] Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [SessionImpl(685169114<open>)][DEBUG][12 Oct 2024 17:38:34,012] () [o.s.o.j.JpaTransactionManager] Not closing pre-bound JPA EntityManager after transaction[DEBUG][12 Oct 2024 17:38:34,012] () [c.b.w.s.WOPIService] putFile()-fwsSavedFileDetails=com.beyondsquare.interfaces.filewriter.entity.FWS_SAVED_FILE_DETAILS@2c40d420[DEBUG][12 Oct 2024 17:38:34,012] () [c.b.w.s.WOPIService] Content-Type...............................: null[DEBUG][12 Oct 2024 17:38:34,037] () [o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet] Failed to complete request: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1[DEBUG][12 Oct 2024 17:38:34,038] () [o.s.o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter] Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter[ERROR][12 Oct 2024 17:38:34,038] () [c.b.ExpiredSessionFilter] callChain()-Error in filter chaining::Input length = 1[ERROR][12 Oct 2024 17:38:34,039] () [c.b.ExpiredSessionFilter] callChain()-Nested exception is::

This is my code for putfile method. getting error in try-catch block
public void putFile(Integer fileId, HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
        LOGGER.debug("putFile()-request.getCharacterEncoding()={}", request.getCharacterEncoding());
        // Retrieve file details using the provided fileId
        LOGGER.debug("putFile()-file_id={}", fileId);
        FWS_SAVED_FILE_DETAILS fwsSavedFileDetails = fwsSavedFileDetailsService.getById(fileId);
        LOGGER.debug("putFile()-fwsSavedFileDetails={}", fwsSavedFileDetails);
        String contentType = request.getContentType();
        LOGGER.debug("Content-Type.......................: {}", contentType);
        // Get headers for lock management
        String requestLock = request.getHeader("X-WOPI-Lock");

        // Handle lock validation if needed (commented out for now)
    /*
    if (requestLock != null && requestLock.equals("IncorrectLockString")) {
        response.setHeader("X-WOPI-Lock", fileData.getLockValue());
        return Response.status(Response.Status.CONFLICT).build();
    }
    */

        File outputFile = File.createTempFile(fwsSavedFileDetails.getFileName(), ".tmp");
        LOGGER.debug("putFile()-outputFile={}", outputFile.getAbsolutePath());

        try (InputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream();
             InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"); // Use UTF-8
             FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile)) {

            // Read the entire input stream into a byte array
            byte[] fileContent = inputStream.readAllBytes(); // Java 9+ method
            LOGGER.debug("putFile()-fileContent={} length={}", fileContent, fileContent.length);

            // Write the byte array to the output file
            fos.write(fileContent);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            LOGGER.error("putFile()-Error occurred::{}", ex.getMessage(), ex);
            throw new RuntimeException("Error writing file: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }

        // Prepare the UploadFileVO object with necessary details
        UploadFileVO uploadFileVO = new UploadFileVO();
        uploadFileVO.setInputStream(new FileInputStream(outputFile));
        LOGGER.debug("putFile()-inputstream={}", uploadFileVO.getInputStream().available());
        uploadFileVO.setContentLength(outputFile.length()); // Use the length of the output file
        LOGGER.debug("putFile()-contentLength={}", uploadFileVO.getContentLength());
        uploadFileVO.setFileName(fwsSavedFileDetails.getFileName());
        uploadFileVO.setArchiveLocation(fwsSavedFileDetails.getFile_path());
        uploadFileVO.setFinalyzerHostname(BSMethod.getHostname(request, userContextAndTokenExpiringCacheService));
        LOGGER.debug("putFile()-finalyzerHostname={}", uploadFileVO.getFinalyzerHostname());
        uploadFileVO.setUserName(fwsSavedFileDetails.getCreated_by());
        LOGGER.debug("putFile()-userName={}", uploadFileVO.getUserName());
        uploadFileVO.setTenantId(fwsSavedFileDetails.getTenant_id());
        uploadFileVO.setTempDirectory((File) request.getServletContext().getAttribute("javax.servlet.context.tempdir"));
        LOGGER.debug("putFile()-tempDirectory={}", uploadFileVO.getTempDirectory());

        // Call the service to write the file
        fws.writeFileInBytes(fwsSavedFileDetails.getApplication_connection_id(), uploadFileVO);
        LOGGER.debug("putFile()-write file from WOPI call success={}", fwsSavedFileDetails.getFileName());
    }

